# Communication Between Node Client and C# Server

Tags: c#, node.js

Im currently working on a NodeJS application that communicates with a c# server. The NodeJS web app receives a request and performs Get:

```
app.get('/api/retrieve', (req, res) => {  
    let client = new net.Socket();
    client.connect(port, host, function() {
        console.log("connected");
    });
    client.on('data', function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
    client.on('close', function(){
        console.log("closed");
    });
});
```

This successfully connects to my c# server:

```
    public void StartListening()
    {
        TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 5000);

        server.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();

            NetworkStream networkStream = client.GetStream();

            while (client.Connected)
            {
                try
                {
                    byte[] message = new byte[1024];
                    networkStream.Read(message, 0, message.Length);
                    var json = Encoding.Default.GetString(message);

                    if (json.Contains("GET /api/retrieve"))
                    {
                        string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_dal.Retrieve());
                        byte[] dataBytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(jsonData);
                        client.GetStream().Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
                    }                        
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When debugging in the browser, I receive the following error:

> Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/retrieve from localhost:3000 to localhost:5000 (HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT).

In Visual Studio, the following exception is caught:

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Also, Visual Studio only catches the above exception after the line **networkStream.Read(message, 0, message.Length);** on the second iteration.

All in all, the .Net application should send a JSON string back to the client NodeJS.

Comment: Is there a reason why you "implement" HTTP yourself?

Comment: I was following a couple of tutorials, is there a better way?

Comment: Well, you could use WCF to build a REST Service for example ...

Comment: For example you could start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/build-a-single-page-application-spa-with-aspnet-web-api-and-angularjs - It's with Angular, but you surely can adapt for pure nodejs, the dotnet part shoud be the same.